# Espresso unit test case for Activity switch in android studio

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I want to write unit test case using Espresso that should check whether the user succesfully navigated from logout page(Activity) to Login Page.
Please let me know if anyboday know this. How to check whether User navigated from Activity A to Activity B  or from  one fragment to another.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in Activity 1, you can press the "navigation" button and use `intended` in Espresso which it's been created to verify that an intent is launched.

```
// Click on the item that starts navigation
onView(withId(R.id.buttonToGoActivity2)).perform(click());

// Check if intent with Activity 2 it's been launched
intended(hasComponent(Activity2.class.getName()));
```

gradle dependency needed:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
```

For a Fragment, maibe you can check if a view inside is showed when navigate to it

```
// Click on the item that starts navigation
onView(withId(R.id.buttonToShowFragment)).perform(click());

// wait for navigation delay
Thread.sleep(2000);

// Check that a view inside the fragment is shown
// Means navigaition to fragment is correct
onView(withId(R.id.viewInFragment)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: hi thanku for replay..  May i know is this the standard way of testing navigation from one page to another :S bcz i am new to unit testing. I mean is this the way everyone are testing navigation

Comment: Check out my last edition. I guess it depend on what you want to test. Have a look to the doc https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/

Comment: One addition. You need to use IntentsTestRule